# Writing to a file with multiple Pools

Tags: python, file-io, multiprocessing

Hi there I am querying some data from a server and I want to store the data I find in a file.  If I don't use pools and multiprocessing, my data writes to a file as it should.  What am I doing wrong here?  Queues were mentioned but I don't think I'm using them properly and I can't figure out how to use them.  I'm very new to multiprocessing

It seems like only the last value is writing to the file, or it doesnt write at all...

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import os
import json
import urllib2
import pprint

start_time = time.time()
localtime = time.localtime()
unixtime = int(time.mktime(time.gmtime()))

if not os.path.exists('data'):
    os.makedirs('data')
filename = ('data/%i_%i_%i_%i_%i_%i') % (localtime[2], localtime[1], localtime[0], localtime[3], localtime[4], localtime[5])
f = open(filename, 'w')

apikey = '_omitted_'

res = 90

lines = (360 * 180) / (res * res)

basepath = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/'+ apikey + '/' 

def getdata(i,j):
    url = basepath + str(j) + ',' + str(i) + ',' + str(unixtime)
    data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
    lat = data['latitude']
    lon = data['longitude']
    temp = data['currently']['temperature']
    humidity = data['currently']['humidity']
    pressure = data['currently']['pressure']
    clouds = data['currently']['cloudCover']
    winddir = data['currently']['windBearing']
    windspd = data['currently']['windSpeed']    
    dewpoint = data['currently']['dewPoint']
    precip = data['currently']['precipIntensity']
    f.write(('%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f\n') % (lat, lon, temp, humidity, pressure, clouds, winddir, windspd, dewpoint, precip))
    #because output needs to be flushed...
    f.close()
#    print('%.2f%% Complete...' % (float(count / lines) * 100))

pool = Pool(processes=1)
for i in range (-180, 180, res):
    for j in range (-90, 90, res):
#        getdata(i,j)
        pool.apply_async(getdata, (i, j))
pool.close()
pool.join()


print('Total time for Execution: %f Minutes' % ((time.time() - start_time) / 60))
```

When I change the number of processes, my output changes, the more processes, the more data displayed in my file.  I think each worker is overwriting another one or overwriting itself.  It seems like each worker is only good to put in one line of text.

Comment: In what way is this failing? Please post an error message or describe the exact problem.  Also, are you sure you need to store everything in one file (which might become very large) written to by multiple processes? The overhead to manage one shared file may wipe out any advantage to using multiprocessing in the first place. In the long run you might be better off with each process writing to a separate file, and then managing a collection of files for later processing (it wouldn't be hard).

Comment: I don't receive any error message but when I look in the file its empty.  I don't need the data to be in any particular order.  The file only gets up to about 50mb at its peak.

Answer (score 0):

So I have come to a solution.  These workers write to the file at their own pace so it's not quite organized, but it works for my purposes.  I think you want to use the callback function to write to the file that way it ensures that the process is complete when it writes.  I still don't think that this is the proper solution but it works.

```
def getdata(i,j):
    url = basepath + str(j) + ',' + str(i) + ',' + str(unixtime)
    data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
    lat = data['latitude']
    lon = data['longitude']
    temp = data['currently']['temperature']
    humidity = data['currently']['humidity']
    pressure = data['currently']['pressure']
    clouds = data['currently']['cloudCover']
    winddir = data['currently']['windBearing']
    windspd = data['currently']['windSpeed']    
    dewpoint = data['currently']['dewPoint']
    precip = data['currently']['precipIntensity']
    return (('%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f\n') % (lat, lon, temp, humidity, pressure, clouds, winddir, windspd, dewpoint, precip))

def writedata(data):
    f.write(data)

pool = Pool(processes=40)
for i in range (-180, 180, res):
    for j in range (-90, 90, res):
        pool.apply_async(getdata, (i, j), callback=writedata)
pool.close()
pool.join()
f.close()
```